# INSERT query not working vb.net sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert, executenonquery

I am working on a project!
M using vb 2012 with .mdf as database!

Problem is M unable to save record to database using the sql insert statement!
PFB "app.config" | "insert code (save button click event)", and help me out!
Its small mistake but m unable to crack it!

```
app.config-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\balancesheet.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
</configuration>

  insert query-->>

 Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveexp.Click
    If descexp.Text <> "" And amountexp.Text <> "" Then
        Dim SQLConnStr As New SqlConnection
        Dim Company As String = ""
        SQLConnStr.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        If SQLConnStr.State = ConnectionState.Broken Or SQLConnStr.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SQLConnStr.Open()
        End If
        cmd.Connection = SQLConnStr
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Expense (date,Description,Amount) values('" & expdate.Value & "', '" & descexp.Text & "','" & amountexp.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Escape `date` like `[date]` as a reserved word?

Comment: you should also use prepared statements and parameters to avoid SQL injection or errors with certain names.

Comment: i changed date to Edate in database and in insert query too!
still no help...!

Comment: ooh...
I will work on it...right now i m requesting for solution for this core coding! as m new to vb and sql!Please help

Comment: are you getting an error?  if [date] is a date type, your SQL is treating it as text.  implement parameters and the problem will likely resolve itself

Comment: i am getting no error!
i guess my cmd.executenonquery is not working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Try
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString()
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Expense] (date,Description,Amount) VALUES('" & expdate.Value & "', '" & descexp.Text & "','" & amountexp.Text & "')"    
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
Finally
con.Close()
End Try
```

I wasnt able to test it.. but i think it should work..

Comment: thnq buddy...but i am getting no result as well as no error as described in catch statement!

Comment: brother!
i got ther error!
but m confused about the solution...!
when i tried to hard code the sql connection string the insert query worked...!!
how can i avoid hardcoding here so that i can publish m desktop ap on other pc with no error!!...??
Please check my app.config
A request :)

Comment: Thats very strange; this way is perfectly fine.. can you test the output of the variable? like:

messagebox.show(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString())

Comment: The only difference between your solutions and my working project is that I first define the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings to a variable (string), and then I use the string for the SqlConnection class. Like this:         Dim ConnectionString as string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString()
        Dim SqlConnection as new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

Comment: Dim ConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString()
        Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        If SqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Or SqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Broken Then
            SqlConnection.Open()
        End If

Comment: NOt working yet..:(
can u please share any small work done by u...!
my project is to make a vb with .mdf as DB in a pc and publish it in 3 different pc's without any connection error...!
can u please share a small example with App.config | and a form where user can insert record..! the code u provided is eas nd only works with select statement..!when i insert any data the DB is still the old even thoug i get no error Message
i would be thankfully thankful if u just help me out.! m actually wasting a lot of time here!
thanx in advance as i know u wont say NO :)

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\QuaackDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: protected static string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

public void plaatsBericht(int userid, string message)
{
    SqlConnection.Open();
    string SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO [bericht] VALUES ( @geplaatstop)";
    using (var SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, SqlConnection))
    {
        SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("geplaatstop", DateTime.Now);
        SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    SqlConnection.Close();
}